# Ajax calls are pending for logged in users

Tags: magento-2.1.7

It's weird but it's happening like adding product to cart or updating mini cart is working fine if no user is logged in. But if user is logged in then adding product to cart, mini cart update, logout checkout page nothing is working. It's continue to load logout page. Mini cart Ajax call will be pending and never completes. Cart page continue to load. Logged user name Ajax call also pending.

It seems nothing is working where ever there is call for customer details. It's production environment and it was working fine till day before yesterday. No system or exception logs.

I have observed that ram usage is going to 99.9 % if I didn't stop any customer related request. It might be database issue or anything

Anyone have any idea on this.

Comment: Enable the exception log also check your Nginx and Apache error log

Comment: @Suman-PHP4U I couldn't find anything. Can I clear quote table. I think its due to abandoned quotes. Its taking time to load the data from mysql and getting time out error if i keep the browser open for long.